# How do I SELECT from sqlite with variable

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

I have a problem querying sqlite database in python with the value of a 
variable. The variable data is populated by a function. The function returns a string. When I write the string directly into the execute string I get the result I want.

I have checked that the variable is containing the string I want, and it is type string.
I have also tried it with a normal variable and session variable.

```
session['client_ip'] = request.remote_addr
session['client_id'] = getUsername(session.get('client_ip'))

print(session.get('client_id'))

with sqlite3.connect('databse.db') as conn:
    conn.row_factory = dict_factory
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT user_id, access_grade FROM users WHERE user_id= 
    (?)', (session.get('client_id'),))
    client = cur.fetchone()
    print(client)
```

I just get value 'None' when querying db. If I just pass a hardcoded string I get the correct response

Comment: Are the last two lines not indented in your real code too? Don't they need to be in the rest of the with block?

Comment: ohh, yeah they are indented correctly in my code.

Comment: If you do `WHERE user_id=?` instead of `WHERE user_id=(?)`, does it work?